# How do I get each line from an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

If I have an NSString with a text file in it, how do I get an NSArray of NSString with each NSString containing a line of the file.

In 10.5 I did this:

```
NSArray* lines = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

But that doesn't work in 10.4, and my program needs to work in 10.4.

As well, it needs to work with \r, \n and \r\n line endings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code is straight from [Apple's documentation regarding paragraphs and line breaks](https://web.archive.org/web/20090408061743/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsParagraphBreaks.html):

```
unsigned length = [string length];
unsigned paraStart = 0, paraEnd = 0, contentsEnd = 0;
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
NSRange currentRange;
while (paraEnd < length)
{
    [string getParagraphStart:&paraStart end:&paraEnd
    contentsEnd:&contentsEnd forRange:NSMakeRange(paraEnd, 0)];
    currentRange = NSMakeRange(paraStart, contentsEnd - paraStart);
    [array addObject:[string substringWithRange:currentRange]];
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if it will work with 10.4

Comment: I compiles without warnings when the target is set to 10.4 and it works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Enumerates all the lines in a string using `enumerateLinesUsingBlock:`

```
[yourString enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString * _Nonnull line, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    //line
}];
```

> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> - (void)enumerateLinesUsingBlock:(void (^)(NSString *line,
>                                    BOOL *stop))block
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `block` The block executed for the enumeration.
>
> The block takes two arguments:
>
> `line` The current line of the string being enumerated. The line
>   contains just the contents of the line, without the line terminators.
>
> `stop` A reference to a Boolean value that the block can use to stop
>   the enumeration by setting *stop = YES; it should not touch *stop
>   otherwise.
>
> **Availability** Available in `OS 10.6` and  `iOS 4.0` and later.

Answer (score 5):

I'll first replace all `\r` with `\n`, then replace all `\n\n` with `\n`, and then do a `componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"`.

Comment: Not the most efficient solution, but +1 for being clever about it

Answer (score 3):

Straight from a project of mine:

```
 NSString * fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
 NSMutableArray * fileLines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"] copyItems: YES];
```

I'm not sure how to make it it automatically work with any type of line ending in 10.4.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html), the NSString message [componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:) is available in OS X 10.5 or later.  You need to use componentsSeparatedByString:.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't tell you how to do it, just why your solution doesn't work in 10.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `enumerateSubstringsInRange:` with the `NSStringEnumerationByLines` and/or `NSStringEnumerationByParagraphs` options.

The benefit of doing it that way is that you get the NSRange of each substring, and can also set the initial range of the string to enumerate.

```
[myString enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, myString.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByLines | NSStringEnumerationByParagraphs usingBlock:^(NSString * _Nullable substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

}];
```