# Reading the first column data from CSV file and compare it with user input?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am developing an app where users can upload a csv file to documents folder of app (I finished it). But I want to give a textfield to users in the app and ask them to enter a id number and this number will be checked with the uploaded csv files first column. If it matches then display an alert saying that its found a match or else it doesn't.

I use the following code but it checks only the first rows first column and not others... I call the function on button click...

```
NSString * pstrCSVFilePath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CSVFile" ofType:@""] 
NSString * pstrCSVFile= [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pstrCSVFilePath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL]; 
NSArray * paRowsOfCSVFile= [pstrCSVFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; 
NSArray * paColumnsOfRow; 
NSString * pstrFirstColumn; 
for(NSString * pstrRow in paRowsOfCSVFile) 
{ 
paColumnsOfRow= [pstrRow componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; 
pstrFirstColumn= [paColumnsOfRow objectAtIndex:0]; 
if([pstrFirstColumn localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:myTextField.text] == NSOrderedSame)
{ 
     //Found the search string in the CSV file.  
break; 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked how many lines you've successfully split your input into? I'd guess that your input file is not linebreaked with \n but maybe \r...

If this is the problem, then you'll be interpreting the file as only having a single row.  Check out this related answer for how to split into lines properly: [How do I get each line from an NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342577/how-do-i-get-each-line-from-an-nsstring). Depending on the version of iOS you're targeting, you can possibly use the method called out in the question itself.